# Displaying Currency Format Issue

Tags: java, android, currency, decimalformat

First post. I'm brand new to software development in general and have spent hours trying to figure this piece out. As you can see, I'm converting a `double` to a `String`, then assigning that value to `textResult` (`String`). I formatted it properly to display decimals, but I can't figure out how to show as currency instead.

Based on what i've found online, it looks like I may have to use

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
```

and then use `nf.format()` somehow but it just doesn't work for me. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void onCalculateDealOne(View v) {

    //get values from text fields
    EditText priceEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etListPriceDealOne);
    EditText unitsEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNumberOfUnitsDealOne);
    EditText couponEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCouponAmountDealOne);


    //get value from result label
    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.perUnitCostDealOne);

    //assign entered values to int variables
    double price = Double.parseDouble(priceEntry.getText().toString());
    double units = Double.parseDouble(unitsEntry.getText().toString());
    double coupon = Double.parseDouble(couponEntry.getText().toString());

    //create variable that holds the calculated result and then do the math
    double calculatedResultDealOne = (price - coupon) / units;

    //convert calculatedResult to string
    String textResult = String.format("%.3f", calculatedResultDealOne);
    result.setText(textResult + " per unit");
    dealOneValue = calculatedResultDealOne;

    //hide the keyboard
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

    //make deal one label visible
    result.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two simple solutions to this. You can use a `DecimalFormat` object, or you can use a `NumberFormat` object.

I personally prefer a `Decimalformat` object because it gives you more precise control over how you would like to format your output value/text.

Some may prefer the `NumberFormat` object because the `.getcurrencyInstance()` method is easier to understand than a cryptic string format (e.g. "$#.00", "#0.00").

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double currency = 123.4;
    DecimalFormat decF = new DecimalFormat("$#.00");
    
    System.out.println(decF.format(currency));

    Double numCurrency = 567.89;
    NumberFormat numFor = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    System.out.println(numFor.format(numCurrency));
}
```

The output for this example program is below:

> $123.40
>
> $567.89

Answer (score 1):

You need to use formatter to format the double value you want, eg:

```
double money = 202.2
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
String moneyString = formatter.format(money);
System.out.println(moneyString);
```